# How to turn on stolen device protection but do not allow iphone to be unlocked without a passcode

Tags: ios, security, touch-id, face-id

I like stolen device protection in iOS 17.3. I want to turn it on. However, I want to require the passcode to unlock the device. I do not want the device to be able to be unlocked with biometrics (touch ID, FaceID) alone.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

No - this isn’t possible today.

You have to enable Touch ID or Face ID before Stolen Device Protection can be enabled.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212510 (Stolen Device Protection)